# Openlayers: search from WFS layer

Tags: javascript, filter, openlayers

I'm using Geoserver/PostGIS/openLayers

I've successfully set a vector layer. And now I'm trying to create a search functionality. But something goes wrong.

This is my code

```js
<form>

<input id="sub01" type="submit" value="Search" onclick="changeFilter()">
</form>


 


<script type="text/javascript">
        OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url="; 
 
 var renderer = OpenLayers.Util.getParameters(window.location.href).renderer;
renderer = (renderer) ? [renderer] : OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers;
 
var WGS84 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); 
var mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"); 

var map = new OpenLayers.Map ("dMap", {    

controls:[
],
maxResolution: 0.005,
displayProjection: WGS84,
 units: 'degrees'
} );


var wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable Features", {
renderers: renderer,
  displayInLayerSwitcher: true,
strategies: [
new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed(),
new OpenLayers.Strategy.Cluster({distance:
15})
],

 styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap(style),

protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
version: "1.1.0",
url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
featureNS :  "http://www.openplans.org/tour",
srsName: "EPSG:4326",
featureType: "tourism",
geometryName: "the_geom"
}),
extractStyles: true,
strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.AND,
filters: [
new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
type: OpenLayers.Filter.
Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
property: prop1,
value: testfil
}),
new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
type: OpenLayers.Filter.
Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
property: prop2,
value: testfil2
})
]
})

});
var prop1 = "tourismtype";
var testfil = "Recreation";
var prop2 = "tourismname";
var testfil2 = "Park";
function changeFilter(prop1, prop2, testfil, testfil2){
wfs.destroyFeatures();
filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.AND,
filters: [
new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
property: prop1,
value: testfil
}),
new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
property: prop2,
value: testfil2
})
]
})
wfs.filter = filter;
    wfs.refresh({force: true});
}

  
    </script>
```

This is not work. I've tried editing my code, I don't know what to do, I've searched for an answer and nothing really helped me. Please advise...

Thanks.

Comment: is there any errors?

Comment: no, I do not have any error

Comment: my map shows the points in primary loading but they do`nt change when click search button, after reload the map it still shows the previous points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved, I put the input element with type submit out of the form element. It works. 
My initial code was:

```
  <form>
Other code
<input id="sub01" type="submit" value="Search" onclick="changeFilter()">
</form>
```

My Correction cod is:

```
 <form>
Other code
</form>
 <input id="sub01" type="submit" value="Search" onclick="changeFilter()">
```